# Office 2007 Ribbon Programming How-to

Tags: ms-office, office-2007, ribbon, customization

I'm interested on how to get the old menus back for Office 2007.  I know you can buy add-ins that do this, but I'm more interested on *how* these are done? I want to implement this at home and just need to be pointed in the correct direction!

Thanks!

Comment: have you read these?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/www7.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37777/Windows-7-Ribbon-Part-1-How-to-Integrate-a-Simple-.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These programs don't actually restore the old menu system, they modify the current Ribbon and then write the code to mock the old design.

This is where you need to start in order to modify the Ribbon.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866%28VS.80%29.aspx

I doubt the Ribbon is going to go away, so you probably will be better off taking the time to get used to it.  I have, and now I much prefer this style menu system.  In fact, I have been looking at code to implement this style in applications that I build.